End of the world ambiance, with corrida, dirty water, and nudism
Remember a movie i have seen less than 15 years ago, where something like the end of the world is coming, or at least the ambiance is about it.
Didn't see the beginning of the film, so maybe i just see the last 30 minutes. (or the last 2 hours)
The actors speaks french. Probably a dubbing, but i am not sure.
Main character is a guy that looks for its girlfriend (seems to be a complicated relationship, maybe because of her frivolity) in the ambiant mess.
Various scenes, probably not correctly ordered:

there is a scene (probably in spain) where a bull runs, and all the peoples run after him in the town streets. Some visible death. (the more i'm thinking about this one, the more i doubt it was in the film. Maybe just a recall of a TV news report)
the main character meet a strange guy, have sex with him during night, and, at the morning, see him commiting suicide, by a swan dive through the window.
an (old?) woman go to wash tomatoes in her kitchen. The water has a very unusual color (yellow/green), so she turn off the tap, but too late : her tomatoes have been touched, she seems to be irritated by this.
A scene takes place in a reception, with rich/opulent peoples that seems to not care (or not be aware) about the global situation. Main character meet peoples he know. They seems disconnected from reality.
main character and its girlfriend walk by night in a town (paris?). She get an idea : they both drop their clothes in a random bin, and run totally naked to their house. Maybe a flashback.
When he found her, the end of the world happen in reverse angle, as a big explosion they watch through a window. (end of the film?)

The ambiance really mark me. Maybe because i didn't see the beginning ? (it wouldn't be the first time)

I can't be sure but this has more than a few elements in common with...
Happy End
also Les derniers jours du monde (original title) (2009)
Wikipedia

Robinson decides to go to Zaragoza, in Spain, to track Laetitia down. He stops in an abandoned boarding school and there is an earthquake. Robinson continues his trip and arrives in Pamplona, where everyone is celebrating the Sanfermines [which included the Running of the Bulls].



...The next morning, all streets are deserted. Robinson stumbles back to the hotel and finds Theo there. They talk and Theo confesses that Robinson has been the love of his life. They kiss but Robinson suddenly stops. He opens the windows as Theo showers, but as he comes out of the bathroom, he jumps off the balcony and dies.



Robinson reaches the castle and enters with the code, he finds a decadent party going on where all the guests are enjoying their last moments on earth before going into the shelter. They are watching porn and having sex, while drinking blue martinis. 



A couple of days later, he arrives in Paris and he walks through the deserted streets. He goes to an apartment and finally meets with Laetitia, who has been waiting for him. A bomb goes off and Robinson dreams of him and Laetitia walking naked through the living streets of Paris. They reach a building where they hide and kiss. A second and fatal bomb explodes.

